# Connection to IBM DB2 in AS400 using JT400 throws Connection was dropped unexpectedly

Tags: java, spring, db2, ibm-midrange, jt400

I'm trying to connect to an IBM DB2 in AS400 using JT400 driver but it thows Connection was dropped unexpectedly exception.

[image]

My application.properties :

[image]

I even tryed it with the hardcode way :

[image]

I just have a question, is this error is related to the configuration ? the credentials are valid (tested with DB2 connect but it's not free).
Or it's related to the AS400 firewall or something else ?
To put you in the context, this application is in the client server, which as he said, that the connection to db2 can be established only within the server given.

Comment: please confirm the exact version of the jt400 driver you are using, and also confirm the version of the i-series (as/400) to which you try to connect.

Comment: JT400 v10.4, DB2 AS400 v9.7

Comment: some mistake, the version of the i-series seems not correct, double check

Comment: I suspecting you are specifying a port number on the URL.  Don't specify a port number and the correct port should be used.

Comment: there was no probleme with the application, it was the clients fault, he was blocking ports with the firewall. after i communicated with him he opened the firewall and i was able to connect. NB : and i didnt use any port number, as @mao said, the correct port used.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as the problem was not with you, and it is no longer an issue.